# Storing Geolocation coordinates to variable returns undefined in console

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm working on the weather app project on freeCodeCamp.org and am having some trouble storing the coordinates into variables.  Here's what my code looks like so far.

```
function userLocation(){
    var lat = 0,
        lon = 0;

    if(navigator.geolocation){
      lon = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(lonPos);
      lat = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(latPos);
    }
    else{ alert("Geolocation not supported by this browser"); }

    return lat, lon;
}

function latPos(position){ return position.coords.latitude; }

function lonPos(position){ return position.coords.longitude; }
```

Inside the `latPos()` and `lonPos()` functions I can do `console.log(position.coords.latitude)` or `longitude` and get my coordinate.  However inside the `userLocation()` function  the `lat` and `lon` variables return `undefined`.  What am I missing here?  Here's a [code pen](https://codepen.io/Optiq/pen/jxVOPK?editors=0010) to the project.

Comment: Why would they ever be undefined in `userLocation` if you initialized them both to `0` at the top of `userLocation`?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head and just looking at your code i guess you should call latPos and lonPos, like:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(lonPos()).

Comment: doesn't work. I get a "cannot read property coords of undefined" error